# Having trouble in JavaScript with Loops and Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, multiple-conditions

Here is the question:

"Write a function addingAllTheWeirdStuff which adds the sum of all the odd numbers in array2 to each element under 10 in array1. Similarly, addingAllTheWeirdStuff should also add the sum of all the even numbers in array2 to those elements over 10 in array1.

BONUS: If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every element in array1."

I got the first part to work. I can't seem to figure out how to get the second part to work. Here is what I have tried:

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2){
  // ADD CODE HERE
  let sumOdd = 0;
  let sumEven = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      sumOdd += array2[i];
    } else {
      sumEven += array2[i];
    }
  }
  for (let i =0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] < 10) {
      array1[i] += sumOdd;
    } else if (array1[i] > 10) {
      array1[i] += sumEven;
    }
  for (let i =0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] > 20) {
      for (let i =0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array1[i] += 1;
        return array1;
      }
        return array1;
    }
  }
  return array1;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make the last part of the question work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code has unbalanced braces. This is the first thing to fix... Secondly, it is a bad idea to `return` in a loop, as then there will not be any other iterations of that loop. Thirdly, why would you want to have a nested loop? If you are the author of the first part of the code, I don't understand how you came to write the second part like that, as you should use the same coding pattern.

Comment: Ok I will check the braces. I used return because I don't know how to make it so if only one item in the array is over 20 that it only adds 1 to it once. That is why I used return to return the array after the first element is found that is over 20. The nested loop was supposed to add 1 to each element in the array if an element in array2 was found to be over 20.

Comment: Yes, but the nested loop is not looping. You exit it upon its first iteration. And from your question it is not clear whether the `>20` check should be on the original values, or on the values after the values were modified by the first phase.

Comment: The BONUS is a bit unclear to me. _"If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every element in array1."_  Does this mean for **every** element in array2 >20  do +1 or if  there is **one or more** elements in array2 > 20 do only once +1?

Answer (score 4):

First Of all I removed, some of the unnecessary braces and balanced them to make it more readable (at least to me)

Then I removed your last nested loop as it was unnecessary and inefficient. While you are looping through `array2` to get `sumOdd` & `sumEven` you can check at the same time if any element is `>20` and store that in a variable (`greaterThan20`). Then when adding the sums you can check that same var to add 1

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {


 // ADD CODE HERE
  let sumOdd = 0;
  let sumEven = 0;
  let greaterThan20 = false; // false by default 
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0)
      sumOdd += array2[i];
    else
      sumEven += array2[i];
    if (array2[i] > 20)// check if any element > 20
      greaterThan20 = true;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] < 10)
      array1[i] += sumOdd;
    else if (array1[i] > 10)
      array1[i] += sumEven;
    if (greaterThan20)// add the +1 if greater than 20
      array1[i] += 1;
  }
  return array1;
}
```

Comment: I like how you used a variable to keep track of greaterThan20. It showed me how to be more flexible in my coding!

Answer (score 1):

you were using `return` in the wrong place which leads the function to stop after the first `number>20` instead of continuing for all numbers

you can also merge the first and the last loop, i just left it like this to be more clearer

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
    // ADD CODE HERE
    let sumOdd = 0;
    let sumEven = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            sumOdd += array2[i];
        } else {
            sumEven += array2[i];
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] < 10) {
            array1[i] += sumOdd;
        } else if (array1[i] > 10) {
            array1[i] += sumEven;
        }

    }
    // moved this outside of the above loop
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (array2[i] > 20) {
            for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                array1[i] += 1;
             //   return array1;    remove this line
            }
            
        }
    }
   return array1;  // now return 
    
}
```

Comment: The text at the start of your answer isn't explaining or clarifying anything. This is too much a code-only answer.

Comment: Right, so now it is a code-only answer. That is not useful. A good answer will explain what the problems are in the Asker's code, and how your code solves them.

Comment: can't you see the comment inside the code ?

Comment: Sure, but how does that explain what the problem was? Important explanations should better appear as an introduction before you present the corrected code.

Comment: True, I hope it's clear now

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Wile testing for odd or even, you can also test for `>20`. In the second loop, just add those numbers too.

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2){
  let sumOdd = 0;
  let sumEven = 0;

  // ==> EXTRA VARIABLE
  let great20 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      sumOdd += array2[i];
    } else {
      sumEven += array2[i];
    }
    // ===> TEST if >20, If so, add one;
    if(array2[i] > 20) ++great20;
   }
   
  for (let i =0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    // ==> ADD great 20
    array1[i] += great20;
    if (array1[i] < 10) {
      array1[i] += sumOdd;
    } else if (array1[i] > 10) {
      array1[i] += sumEven;
    }
        return array1;
    }
   return array1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code as someone pointed out, you had a return statement in your inner loop which was breaking out of the loop.

I also added here an alternative solution, just for diversity. First calculate odd and even sums using filter and reduce. I also check if any element is over 20. Based on true/false value of arr2.some, I map over the arr1

```js
const arr1 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21]

function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(arr1, arr2) {
  let oddSum = arr2.filter(el => el % 2 != 0).reduce((a, n) => a + n)
  let evenSum = arr2.filter(el => el % 2 == 0).reduce((a, n) => a + n)
  const over20 = arr2.some(el => el > 20)
  if (over20) {
    return arr1.map(el => el > 10 ? el += ++evenSum : el += ++oddSum)
  } else {
    return arr1.map(el => el > 10 ? el += evenSum : el += oddSum)
  }
}
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const addingAllTheWeirdStuff=(a,b)=>a.map(i=>(i>10?i+b.reduce((s,c)=>s+((c%2)?c:0),0):((i<10)?i+b.reduce((s,c)=>s+(!(c%2)?c:0),0):i))+b.some(e=>e>20));
```

Comment: i love it (assuming it works)! but I don't think that's gonna work for him :)

Comment: I don't like answers which are just code.

Comment: nope, wrong answer as well